# Populate a GridView with selected Installed Apps in Android

Tags: android, gridview

I don't have any info regarding this. How can I populate my GridView with selected installed application and run those apps?

I got a tutorial site but couldn't follow it easily since I am new to Android. http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/how-to-write-custom-launcher-app-in-android/

Main Activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.allapps_screen);

    gv_selectedApps = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gv_selectedApps);

    gv_selectedApps.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));

    gv_selectedApps.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(
               getApplicationContext(),
               ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label))
               .getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of installed apps from this code

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0)
```

Comment: thanks for your response. How can I put that in my gridView? And I'd like to get only 1 to 3 applications, NOT ALL installed apps.

Comment: Now you have the app's list, Filter your Apps list based on your requirement. And write a customAdapter and pass this App's list for the adapter as data.

checkout this link
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/android-custom-grid-view-example-with-image-and-text.html

Comment: I am catching an error 02-07 15:56:54.914: E/AndroidRuntime(12750): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.pm.ResolveInfo cannot be cast to com.example.launcher